# Should a session timeout or a form authentication timeout log off the user?

Tags: c#, web-config, forms-authentication, session-timeout

I'm slightly puzzled with what should log out a user.

At the moment I have a session timeout set to 20 minutes and I thought that once the session expires the user should be logged out.

I can add a code that will do that on a session_end.

I came across a form authentication timeout in a web.config. Currently it's set to 48 hours.

I have changed the authentication timeout to 20 minutes and that's doing the job.

So should a session time out log out the user or should this be done by a form authentication time out?

Thank you

**Edit:**

What I'm facing at the moment, is that session variables get set to 0, which is fine because the session has timed out. But I would have thought that the user will be logged out too.

Am I correct to say that authentication data is always stored in the cookies and that cookie will be cleared only once I hit the form authentication timeout?

Therefore what I'm facing is expected behaviour. User losses session but he's still logged in because the authentication information is stored in the cookie.

In that case I can set session timeout to be exactly the same as the form authentication time out. Assumption here is that form authentication timeout gets refreshed when the user does anything on the website.

Another alternative is to add code into sesseion_end method where I will log the user out.

**Edit 2:**

Does an authentication timeout gets refreshed at the same time as a session time out?

**Edit 3:**

Came across this ***"Sliding expiration resets an active authentication cookie's time to expiration upon each request during a single session."*** which I believe is what I'm trying to achieve. If the session and the authentication timeout are the same than the authentication timeout will be reset each time a session timeout is reset and this should do the job. Any feedback is welcome...

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the nature of your web application. Most *regular* websites (eg. StackOverflow) do not log a user out when the session ends. However, with security critical websites (ie. banks) the login state of the user is dependent on the session, which is usually reduced to just a few minutes.

By the sounds of it your web form is dependent on the user being logged in and if that is solely dependent on the session then you will need to ping the server to keep the session alive.

Unless the form is requesting secure/personal information then I wouldn't impose a short time limit on its completion. It wouldn't have been the first time I've half completed a form, gone to bed and finished it in the morning!

Comment: This makes it cleared. I'm not actually interested in logging the users out once the session is cleared. The users shouldn't be permitted to carry out certain actions if they don't have session variables for X, Y, Z. 

Also I don't understand why is it a bad practice to have form authentication timeout to be the same as a session timeout? The recommendatinos that I came across said that the form authentication timeout should be double of a session time out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Form Authentication can be set to use cookies to track the user.  That is probably what is happening.