# timeout attribute on forms doesn't effect and it expires after a few minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am programming an application in ASP.NET MVC. The authentication is through the Forms. I have this entry in my `web.config`:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="StudioN/Login" timeout="99999"></forms>
  </authentication>
```

and I have set the timeout to 99999, but it expires a few minutes (less than 30 minutes) after I have logged in. How can prevent it and have a timeout suppose 99999 (I mean as long as user has the website on the browser)?

Comment: Try to set session timeout `<sessionState timeout="10"></sessionState>`. Maybe you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144868/timeout-in-authentication-does-not-work-properly).

Comment: @KyleWang:I added  <sessionState timeout="99999"></sessionState> into web.config, but it expired less than 30 minutes