# Signout Formsauthentication user in Session_End or SignOut(?)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, forms-authentication, asp.net-4.0

This is a webform asp.net 4 application. The Formsauthentication method is used.

web.config:

```
<sessionState
    mode="InProc"
    cookieless="false"
    timeout="1"/>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx"
      loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
      slidingExpiration="true"
      timeout="25" />
</authentication>
```

The problem is that, when a user logouts, I need to perform some actions (e.g., logging something in the DB).

The case when a user click on "logout" link is pretty easy.

Now I am dealing with logout due to timeout, and I'm facing two different scenarios:

1. The session expires and the authorization doesn't
2. The authorization token expires and the session is still valid

In scenario #1, I tried the following:

```
Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session("Username")) Then
        Try
            ' custom action..
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Session.Clear()
            Session.Abandon()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' log the exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

but here I have two huge problems: **User** is not available in this context (i.e., I can't chech User.Identity.isAuthenticated, therefore I'm checking Session("Username")) and **FormsAuthentication.SignOut()** raises a nullreferenceException.
How can I logout the user from the FormsAuthentication "zone"?

Scenario #2 is more complex, as I read that there is not an explicit event fired when the authorization is expired. My "willing" is to be able to perform the same *custom actions* for the user just a moment before the expiration happens.
Is it possible in some way?

Will some sort of custom authentication provider let me handle these cases in a better and more robust way?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a custom provider that handles it any better, but one way i handled this in the past was to set session sliding expiration much higher than authentication timeout in web.config. That way I only ever had one scenario to deal with: losing auth token but valid session. Much easier to handle it with 
if(!User.IsAuthenticated)
{...do whatever and go to sign in page...}

[Forms Authentication Timeout vs Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout)