# Endless Session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, infinite

I am calling a page using ajax/jquery after every 5 mins but still my session gets killed and application redirects to login page.

Is it because of forms authentication? I have the following code in my web.config.

`<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>`

I have not specified session timeout in web.config, which means by default it will use 20 mins. But as I am calling a page after every 5 mins it should maintain session right?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the application pool time out (in IIS - web site properties) and increase it if needed. Most shared Hosting providers decreased this valus to save server resources.

Regards