# ASP.NET Login not logout on timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication, authorization

My asp.net form authentication never logs out.

I've seted up timeout on it:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="1">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

But after 5 minute waiting i update page, and i am still logged in. RememberMe option is set to false.

I doing login in next way:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
  Session.Clear();
  e.Authenticated = Authorization.RequestLogin(login_obj.UserName, login_obj.Password);
}
```

And checking am i logged in:

```
if(!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  Server.Transfer("~/deny.aspx");
```

But i am always loged i and newer redirected to deny.aspx

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have a look [Forms Authentication Timeout vs Session Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout)