# Session Timeout doesnt work in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, session

I have checked various questions asked in SO in this topic also tried the solutions provided for the various questions, but it doesnt work for me. 
My application is ASP .Net4.5, I store username, usertype in session and later it is used while inserting data to the SQL tables. I have set the session time out in webconfig as follows.

```
  <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" name=".mycookie" timeout="60"></forms>
  </authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```

In the IIS settings against Sessionstate the following were set

```
SessionState = In Process
Cookie settings -> Mode = Use Cookies
                   Name = ASP.Net_SessionId
                   Timeout (min) = 60
```

I'm not sure whether I'm setting this in wrong way in the above settings. The issue is my application session timeouts much before the set time, I feel it gets timeout in 10-15 minutes. Please advise how to set the timeout value correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config

Comment: @Anil, My webconfig file already has the values mentioned in your reference, but still it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting session timeout, but it didnt worked for me. I decided to store those session variables used in cookies, and read from cookies. Now there is no session timeout issue. I clear the cookies while login to the application, also set the expiry to 1 day to avoid any issue. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are getting problem with form authentication timeout and session timeout. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in web config file.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="50"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```