# SessionState TimeOut is not working Properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wanna Prevent auto logout from website for 1 day, the solution that I found is

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1440" />
```

notice that my authentication mode is none `<authentication mode="None" />`

Set in my `Web.config` > `system.web` tag

I also Used

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="SignIn.cshtml" protection="All" path="/SignIn" timeout="1440" />
</authentication>
```

but its not working and authentication expire after 20-30 min and need to login again. any body can help? Is there any other config that I should set?

Answer (score 0):

Use this configuration in your web config file

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks bt, as I said its not working.. I even set ( mode="InProc" cookieless="false" ) to make sure about default attributes..

Answer (score 0):

There are two timeouts Authentication timeout vs Session timeout. For authentication timeout value set `timeout` property on `<forms>` element in web.config.

Check following SO posts:

[Forms authentication timeout vs sessionState timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812994/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-sessionstate-timeout)

[Forms Authentication Timeout vs Session Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout)

Comment: Thanks! I Edited the question according to my requirement.

Comment: If your authentication mode is none then how are your users authenticated?

Comment: Im using a simple form and jquery for pass parameters to account controller and `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` authorise user..

Comment: I used this code but it didnt work also `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="SignIn.cshtml" protection="All" path="/SignIn" timeout="1440" />
    </authentication>`

Comment: Please check if you have method call `app.UseCookieAuthentication` in your code. If yes, set `ExpireTimeSpan` property. For information check: https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/